# How to convert project from Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight to Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I upgraded my project on Visual Studio 2015 by clicking right button on project and "Upgrade project to 8.1 version".
However, it added Silverlight too and I don't need it.

Now: "Windows phone Silverlight 8.1

Needed: "Windows phone 8.1.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Windows 8.1 of an existing Silverlight app just adds more functionality but not the underlaying framework. There is a big difference in Silverlight and WinRT apps and you cannot port them by a button click. You would need to change everything by hand.

Comment: How can that be done? Facebook oauth library doesn't support silverlight projects. That's why I need to remove silverlight